# Check a column value in SQL stored procedure for non numeric characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I currently have a sql stored procedure that I run to check for incorrect values during data entry.  The problem I am having is that certain values that should be generating an error message are being accepted as correct values.  Currently any value that contains a non numeric character (0-9) should be flagged as an incorrect value and generate a message. for example 12345678P is being rejected while 1234L5678 is being accepted.

I am trying to capture the errors with a qualifiers as seen below as follows

```
case when TRY_CONVERT(bigint,column_name) is null or column_name Like '%[^0-9]%' then 'Non numeric character in reference number'
```

Any thoughts or ideas on how to screen for those non numeric characters or suggestions to fix my case?  Thank you.

This question is different from the already asked question that is linked because I am not trying to strip out non numeric characters but rather only recognize they exist and generate a message based on that.

Comment: What values are being accepted that you think should be rejected?

Comment: Added examples into original post but will add them here as well. 123456789P is being rejected while 1234L5678 is being accepted.

Comment: As you're using SQL Server, can you use `ISNUMERIC()`? Or for SQL Server 2012 there's a newer `TRY_PARSE()`. Some notes here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manub22/2013/12/23/use-new-try_parse-instead-of-isnumeric-sql-server-2012/

Comment: @Tom I cannot replicate your results using your case statement with those values both show as Non numeric.  Perhaps you can share more of your code than just the case statement so we can see if something else might be affecting it?

Comment: @SamHolloway ISNUMERIC() will allow for $ money, decimals commas, 10e10 (exponents) and more because his case statement says Non numeric character in reference number I would assume he probably doesn't want some of those cases to be true.  TRY_PARSE will act similar to TRY_CONVERT & TRY_CAST but the result will be a string instead of the specific datatype checked. there shouldn't be a reason to abandon TRY_CONVERT to use TRY_PARSE http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/manas1/tryparse-tryconvert-and-trycast-in-sql-server/

Comment: unfortunanetly having tried both `isnumeric()` or `TRY_PARSE()` neither of them generate the necessary error message.

Comment: I would suggest you write a function for this, loop through every character with the accept/fail logic you are seeking.  I don't see isnumeric() having any way it could possibly work for what you seek.  I don't use Parse but I don't see how that can work for your stated purpose either.  A function looking at each character should work.  It sounds like you want to accept only character data.  Filtering out numeric data will not solve that because you have symbols as possibles also.  I would loop through check if the ascii value of the character was in the range for upper and lower case letters.

Comment: I don't want to filter anything i just want to flag the whole value and generate a message. I am looking to only accept 0123456789 no other characters. I may just have to go look and each character individually and examine the ascii.

Comment: There is no need to resort to looping for something so simple.

Comment: I added a new answer to the question flagged as being a duplicate because the accepted answer there is not a good approach anymore. 6 years ago when it was authored things were different than they are today.